# Template Updates do not happen in test

Tags: angular, testing, angular-material, jasmine

I am working through testing Angular code and seem to have some misunderstanding about template updates.
What I am trying to get to work:
I implemented a component which is a simply searchInput that can be cleared by a button click. [Template below] This works fine in practise, but I want to write a test for it.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
  <input #searchInput matInput (input)="onSearch(searchInput.value)"
         [placeholder]="placeholder">
  <button class="clear-search-button" mat-button *ngIf="searchInput.value" matSuffix mat-icon-button 
          (click)="searchInput.value=''; onSearch('')">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

My test currently looks like this [de = fixture.debugElement]:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NoopAnimationsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule],
      declarations: [SomeSearchComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeSearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should reset Input on button input', () => {
    const input = de.query(By.css('input'));
    expect(input).not.toBeNull();
    input.value = 'someSearch';

    fixture.detectChanges(); // Update view since now the input.value allows 
                                the button to get added to DOM, since *ngIf-condition is now true.

    const resetBtn = de.querySelector('button');
    resetBtn.click();

    fixture.detectChanges(); // Update view since now the input.value should be updated.

    expect(input.value).toEqual('');
  });
```

My problem is, that however I try to get the button, it does not seem to be added to the DOM, since I always get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null' on the `resetBtn.click()` line.

Is there a fundamental problem with my understanding of template testing or is there any silly typo?

Comment: Is your component using the OnPush strategy?

Comment: I believe you are setting value using input.value which does not update the template. Instead set a value to searchInput.value and then the button will be visible in DOM and you should be able to execute your test case.

Comment: @Eliran Els Yes it does. How is that a Problem?

Comment: @Sneha How would I go about referencing it?

Comment: @chund Try to override your component in the TestBed to work with default Change Detection.
`TestBed.overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
  set: new Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: ``,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
  })
});`

Comment: I completely removed the ChangeDetection, with no effect on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you probably think the function of input is getting triggered but it's not. While the dom isn't triggered this is problaby happening cause you just enterered the text but within a test the input event is not triggered you have to trigger it manual.

What you have to do is trigger it like:

```
input.value = 'someSearch';
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

My example:

```
let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
input.value = '11';
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-test-run-draft-1eta9b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: Interesting idea, but I do not see how the onSearch() function being called or not should do anything, since the btn only relies on the value of searchInput being present.
In addition I now get `input.dispatchEvent is not a function`

Comment: Put down my example in the edit. I had lots of trouble with the dom not changing aswell, so my try it out.

Comment: Also you maybe want to add your testbed to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I added it

Comment: Added a working example. Think what you're missing is the `nativeElement`.

Comment: I take it back. everything now works. Although i do not get why the function call should have anything to do with it. Can you elaborate on this maybe?

Comment: Normally you not use `#searchInput` you use a ngModel or a reactive form. So this will require to change the component value with the `input` or `ngModelChange` event. Which then will trigger the `*ngIf`.